# System copyarray cannot be applied object --> int[]?

Tags: java, arrays

i was trying:

```
private int[] data = new int[1];
int[] newArr = new int[1];
System.arraycopy(data, 0, newArr, data.length);
```

but i'm getting:

```
error: method arraycopy in class System cannot be applied to given types;
                System.arraycopy(data, 0, newArr, data.length);
                      ^
  required: Object,int,Object,int,int
  found: int[],int,int[],int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error

Compilation Failed
```

i was sure its ok to copy `int[]` anything i'm doing wrong?

Comment: `actual and formal argument lists differ in length` - I would start with that statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just missing the last argument to the method, [here's](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) the javadoc and this is what it says aout the arguments:

> src - the source array.
>
> srcPos - starting position in the source array.
>
> dest - the destination array.
>
> destPos - starting position in the destination data.
>
> length - the number of array elements to be copied.

Below should work:

```
int[] data = new int[1];
int[] newArr = new int[1];
System.arraycopy(data, 0, newArr, 0, data.length);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArr));
```

Answer (score 1):

As discussed you're missing an argument. But since you're copying the whole array, you could also use a simpler method:

```
int[] newArr = data.clone();
```